# Replace Dash and Space in a single statement

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace both dash (-) and white space to an empty character.

**Current String**

```
String number = +880 199-8017580
```

**Desired String**

```
String number = +8801998017580
```

I tried this way

`String number = number.replaceAll("-|\\s","");`

But not works.

Comment: Can you try with `[-| \\s]` , I think you're missing a space ` `

Comment: Posted code works here. You're not consistent with `number` and `phoneNumber` in the question. And the more usual pattern would look like `String number = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[-|\\s]+","");`

Comment: @isstiaung `\\s` matches all whitespace.

Comment: Ah my bad. Then, what @ElliottFrisch said ^

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Perhaps. OP wants digits and `+`. Which would imply a pattern based on `\\D` (or I would think so anyway). I think Emma is on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable is called number, you are using phoneNumber instead.

To match either character you could also add them to a character class `[-\\s]` instead of using an alternation `-|\\s`

```
String number = "+880 199-8017580";
number = number.replaceAll("[-\\s]+","");
System.out.println(number); // +8801998017580
```

Note that you can omit the `|` from the character class as it would literally match the pipe.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/wgjq2U)

Comment: I have so many number. does this is code good for performance? and what about if i want to remove + with 88 digit. Means the result should "01998017580"

Comment: @ShihabUddin If you use the character class version with the quantifier `[\\s-]+` that would be better than the `-|\\s` version with the alternation. In that case you could use `^[+]88|[\s-]+` and replace with an empty string. See https://regex101.com/r/rb88nU/1

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can capture our desired chars, then those undesired,

```
([+]?[0-9]+)|(.+?)
```

and make a simple replacement.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([+]?[0-9]+)|(.+?)";
final String string = "+880 199-8017580\n"
     + "+880 199-801-7580\n"
     + "880  199-801-7580\n"
     + "(880)  199-801-7580\n"
     + "(880)  199-801-7580  ";
final String subst = "\\1";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CzYACz/1/)

Comment: Just as a sidenote, the second capturing group is not used. The `.*?` will only match a single char as there if nothing after it making it expand. I think the expression could also be `([+]?[0-9]+)|.`